# java.io.File v. org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileObject

Tags: java, apache, io

I'm trying to monitor a folder for a batch file that will be dropped there to make updates to a web app. The app already uses the Apache vfs2 library and I've been advised by my lead to use this as well.

My question is this: what is the conceptual difference between File in java.io and FileObject in org.apache.commons.vfs2?

I've read the docs at [FileObject](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/FileObject.html) and [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and what I'm really looking for is a conceptual distinction of these two classes. For example: is FileObject some kind of wrapper around File? I don't see much in common in their inheritance trees so it doesn't seem to me like FileObject is using File anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VFS2 `FileObject` is an interface with no ties to a specific storage mechanism (this is the point of the VFS2 filesystem)

A `FileObject` can represent a local filesystem file, a file on an SFTP, FTP, HTTP or WebDav server, or a file inside a compressed archive, or any other thing you can think of that might hold a collection of bytes that make up a file.

`java.io.File` is a reference to a local file, and that's the end of it.

The benefit of the `FileObject` abstraction is that you can code to a single interface, and not care about where the bytes that make up that file actually come from (i.e. local filesystem, streamed via SFTP over SSH, via HTTP etc.)